# Sqlite3 does not work after packaged in Electron application

Tags: sqlite, electron, knex.js

```js
{
  "name": "ele-sqlite",
  "productName": "CUSTOMER MANAGER",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "electron app with sqlite",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "build-win32": "electron-packager . customer manager --platform=win32 --icon=assets/icon.ico --prune=true --out ./dist --overwrite"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.10.5",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.3.5",
    "knex": "^0.95.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.11.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

I am new to programming in general. I am trying to create a simple Electron app to store client details. Everything work very well in development and when I pack the application with electron-packager. I am
not able to store anything in the database. I have googled and apply many of the solutions but it without luck.
package.json below

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Menu } = require('electron');
const { rebuild } = require('electron-rebuild');

// Set Env
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

let mainWindow;

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1400,
      height: 900,
      title:"All In One",
      center: true,
      show: false,
      webPreferences: {
              nodeIntegration: true,
              contextIsolation: false
          }

  });

 mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {mainWindow.show()})

// Build menu from template
const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
// insert menu
Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

//Info from database
  const {add, listAll, findByName, update, remove}  = require('./models/dbHelpers.js')


  ipcMain.on("mainWindowLoaded",  () => {
    let resultList = listAll()
      resultList.then(function(customerList){
        mainWindow.webContents.send("list:customers", customerList)
      }); 
    });
    // Recieve data to add customer
    ipcMain.on('add:customer', (event, data) =>{
      add(data)
      console.log(data);
      event.sender.send('add:customer', ' Customer Created!!!')

    })

    // Recieve data to delete customer
    ipcMain.on('delete:customer', (event, id) =>{
      //console.log(id)
      remove(id);
      event.sender.send('deleted:customer-database', 'Customer Deleted!!')
    })

    // Update customer
    ipcMain.on('edit:customer', (event, id, data) =>{
      console.log(id, data)
      update(id, data);
      event.sender.send('Update:customer-database', ' Customer Updated!')
    })

  }); // App ready & create window

const mainMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Quit',
        click(){
          app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]


app.on("window-all-closed", () => {app.quit()})
```

Comment: Hi Mario, let us know what is the error message you're getting. Or what happens when you're trying to insert something to the database

Comment: Thanks for your replay. The error I get is that electron-rebuid is missing. This is a dev-dep. and is not supposed to be on the final packaged application. Now I am going to rebuild my sqlite3 database without knex.js to see if this is the problem.